# Converting Powerpoints into HTML dynamically

Tags: php, html, powerpoint

I am trying to convert the Powerpoints that users of my website have uploaded to HTML so other people can see them.

I am using the followiong code but nothing happens...

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>ShotDev.Com Tutorial</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<?  
$ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application");  
$ppApp->Visible = True;  

$strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]))); // C:/AppServ/www/myphp  

$ppName = "Teste.pptx";  
$FileName = "MyPP/MyPPt";  

//*** Open Document ***//  
$ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName));  

//*** Save Document ***//  
$ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$FileName,14);  
//$ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs(realpath($FileName),14);  

$ppApp->Quit;  
$ppApp = null;  
?>  
PowerPoint Created <a href="<?=$FileName?>.htm">Click here</a> to View.  
</body>  
</html>
```

The error is:

Class 'COM' not found in /home/webitcloud/public_html/PW/1617/weduc/Teste4/Index.php on line 7

The name of my Powerpoint is Teste.pptx.

Comment: add `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` in your php.ini file.

Comment: Where is my php.ini?